# Trouble when encode base64 string from firebase to RecylclerView

Tags: android, firebase, base64, firebase-realtime-database

My Apps running with firebase and successfull upload image encode to string this my json

My Json on Firebase

[image]
MyAdapter.java

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
    String name = movies.get(position).getName();
    String desk = movies.get(position).getDescription();

    holder.nameTxt.setText(name);
    holder.tvDesk.setText(desk);

    String image = movies.get(position).getImageFile();
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    holder.ivprofile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    PiccassoClient.downloadImage(c,movies.get(position).getUrl(),holder.img);
}
```

logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                        Process: com.squad.utif.rvtext, PID: 2543
Theme: themes:{}                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes()' on a null object reference
at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:118)
at com.squad.utif.rvtext.Recycler.MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:49)
at com.squad.utif.rvtext.Recycler.MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:23)
```

whats going wrong with encode?

Comment: try to `clean` the project and `rebuild` it.

Comment: thankyou for your comment but still not work ;(

Comment: I think the problem on the getImagefile() , but I dont know how to resolve it

Comment: The problem is indeed that `movies.get(position).getImageFile()` seems to return null. I don't immediately see why that is and there is not enough information to allow me to reproduce the problem. In general storing images in the Firebase Database has caused most people problems and pain. I *highly* recommend transitioning over to the new [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start), which is a way better fit for storing images.

Comment: thank you @FrankvanPuffelen for your recommend, I will learn more about new firebase, hope I dont stuck while implement it :D

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do you know of any open source projects that use Firebase Storage and Firebase Authentication together?